# Content-Security-Policy hash of script

Tags: hash, xss, http, html, content-security-policy

```
<?php
header("Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'sha256-".base64_encode(hash('sha256', 'console.log("Hello world");', true))."'");
?>
<script>console.log("Hello world");</script>
```

However I still receive in Chrome:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "default-src
>   'sha256-1DCfk1NYWuHM8DgTqlkOta97gzK+oBDDv4s7woGaPIY='". Either the
>   'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce
>   ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that
>   'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a
>   fallback.

I've toyed with this for over an hour but still am unable to generate a hash that matches examples eg.

http://software-security.sans.org/downloads/appsec-2014-files/building-a-content-security-policy-csp-eric-johnson.pdf
Claims `<script>alert('Allowed to execute');</script>` (hard to determine original spacing) has hash of `sha256-MmM3YjgyNzI5MDc5NTA0ZTdiCWViZGExZDkxMDhlZWIw NDIwNzU2YWE5N2E4YWRjNWQ0ZmEyMDUyYjVkNjE0NTk=`

Which doesn't make much sense: the last part doesn't start with `sha256-`, but at least the first hash is the correct length. I get `sha256-nbFv/38jW7zf8mQirwFemFjDwp5CwIaorxe4Z3yycn0=` as the hash for `alert('Allowed to execute');`

http://nmatatal.blogspot.com/2013/09/how-my-script-hash-poc-works.html
Claims:
`<script>console.log("Hello world");</script>` should have a csp of
`script-src 'sha256-y/mJvKQC/3H1UwsYAtTR7Q=='` eyeballing it, that looks too short.

---

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey, wanted to follow up on the link referenced. sha256 isn't supported, just sha1. I think the value would be fU8Y3i83rje0823mI+3hgmqgysc= but I haven't tested. Updated the docs accordingly and that link now points to a blog using script hash.

Comment: For anybody stumbling here with my same problem, it seems that Chrome calculates hashes using Unix newlines, not Windows new lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE: it seems script hashes are not supported in the Chrome release version. My test only works in Chrome Canary (when using `script-src`, **not** `default-src`)

——

You should try using "script-src" instead of "default-src" (based on my quick reading of the [working draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP11/#hash-usage-for-script-elements))

Comment: This is the test page that works in Chrome Canary: http://pastebin.com/2pnT728f

Comment: I actually switched from script-src to default-src because it wasn't working for me. Your update makes sense why neither was working for me.

Comment: I read the draft but wasn't sure how to treat proceeding and trailing whitespace in `<script>` tags. I'll do some test and see if I can find out what Chrome Canary does.

Answer (score 10):

This is still incredibly confusing. I'm running Chrome 40 and like you I've just spent far longer than I would have liked figuring out what's going on.

[The CSP 2 spec says this about hashing <script> elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#script-src-hash-usage):

> For example, the SHA-256 digest of `alert('Hello, world.');` is `YWIzOWNiNzJjNDRlYzc4MTgwMDhmZDlkOWI0NTAyMjgyY2MyMWJlMWUyNjc1ODJlYWJhNjU5MGU4NmZmNGU3OAo=`.

I've managed to generate that hash by running:

```
$ echo -n "alert('Hello, world.');" | openssl dgst -sha256 | base64
YWIzOWNiNzJjNDRlYzc4MTgwMDhmZDlkOWI0NTAyMjgyY2MyMWJlMWUyNjc1ODJlYWJhNjU5MGU4NmZmNGU3OAo=
```

But this does **not** work in Chrome 40.

[The editor's draft of CSP says this](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec/specs/content-security-policy/#script-src-hash-usage):

> For example, the SHA-256 digest of `alert('Hello, world.');` is `qznLcsROx4GACP2dm0UCKCzCG+HiZ1guq6ZZDob/Tng=`.

The example they give is generated with:

```
$ echo -n "alert('Hello, world.');" | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | base64
qznLcsROx4GACP2dm0UCKCzCG+HiZ1guq6ZZDob/Tng=
```

The addition of the `-binary` flag to `openssl` is the difference between the two commands.

This does work in Chrome 40 (stable) and Chrome Canary, but I believe it still has issues in Firefox 36.

Comment: This commit makes it seem like the first hash was never correct: https://github.com/w3c/webappsec/commit/19b3773c51465fd2ea32f6e0be7b39325a949b89

Comment: It gets worse :) -- Firefox will write a warning to the console and POST a violation report even if the correct hash is provided.  See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1128195 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

https://security.stackexchange.com/a/34998/41628

> So it looks that all you have to do (for the time being, until Chrome
>   updates to reflect the status change of the CSP 1.1 proposal) is, to
>   change the header name back to X-Content-Security-Policy.